# Highlight a row based on its first cell date value

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have a sheet with the first column representing date values (e.g. 09/04/14), and I'm looking for some way to make calc highlight the current day's row.

I already used `Format -> Conditional Formatting -> Formula is` to highlight even rows using

```
ISEVEN(ROW())
```

formula and I know that I can obtain the current date using `today()` function.
What is left is to extract the first cell's value in a row (with DATE type) and compare it with `today()`. How can I do this? Or maybe there is a simpler way to do the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the cursor in cell A1 then select the entire sheet.

Go to conditional formatting, and choose Formula, and use:

```
$A1=TODAY()
```

This formula will be applied to all cells, but the test will only happen to the first column, because we have put the dollar sign against the column part.

Provided your first column is an actual date, this should *just work*.

However, if the column just contains a string that looks like a date, then use the following to convert the text to an actual date value:

```
DATEVALUE($A1)=TODAY()
```

Then set the format as you want it.